# can't parse next word in char array using strtok

Tags: c, string-parsing

```
#include"shell.h"

int main()
{
    char cInput[50];
    char cCopy[50];
    char *pCommand;
    char pArguement[10];
    bool bRun = true;

    while(strcmp(pCommand, "exit"))//run untill exit
    {
        printf("[myshell]%% ");

        cin >> cInput;  //get command from user

        for(int i=0; i<50; i++)
            cCopy[i] = cInput[i];

        //get command
        pCommand = strtok(cInput, " ");

        if(!strcmp(pCommand, "pwd"))
        {  
            printf("No FUNCTIONAILITY FOR PWD! \n");
        }
        else if(!strcmp(pCommand, "list"))
        {
            printf("No FUNCTIONAILITY FOR LIST! \n");
        }
        else if(!strcmp(pCommand, "history"))
        {
            printf("No FUNCTIONAILITY FOR HISTORY! \n");
        }
        else if(!strcmp(pCommand, "prompt"))
        {
            // pCommand = strtok(cCopy, "y");

            while(pCommand != NULL)
            {
                printf(" %s \n", pCommand);

                pCommand = strtok(NULL, " ");
            }
            return 0;
        }
        else//command not found
        {
            printf("%s: Command not found \n", pCommand);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So I'm trying to follow the example of strtok from the C standard library, but I can't figure out why I'm unable to get the next word from the cstring cInput. I was under the impression that using:

```
while(pCommand != NULL)
{
    printf(" %s \n", pCommand);

    pCommand = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

would result in getting the next words.

Any help?
Thanks!

Comment: `cin >> cInput;` Space is separator. It does not include spaces or later. try `cin.getline(cInput, 50);`

Comment: Strange right shift `>>` in this C problem.  Suggest `fgets(cInput, sizeof cInput, stdin);`  Hmmm Maybe C++?

Comment: You'll be surprised. Print the value of cInput before the function call and you'll see it only contains 1 word. cin, as @BLUEPIXY says, is terminated by whitespace.

Comment: Haha oh wow that's a rookie mistake. Thanks, I'll see if I can get it working now

Comment: Yeah that's the problem, Not sure how to mark your comment as the answer, but thanks BLUEPIXY

Comment: `while(strcmp(pCommand, "exit"))` gives you undefined behavior the first time through the loop, since `pCommand` is not initialized at that point.